# unable to print output to stdout within sources of libxml2

Tags: c, libxml2

I want to debug sources of libxml2, for that, I would like to print some statements within some functions.
However, the print statements, like below do not result in anything in the console

I have put these within a file xmlschemas.c and in function xmlSchemaParse

```
xmlSchemaPtr
xmlSchemaParse(xmlSchemaParserCtxtPtr ctxt)
{
    xmlSchemaPtr mainSchema = NULL;
    xmlSchemaBucketPtr bucket = NULL;
    int res;
#ifdef fprintf
#undef fprintf
#endif

#ifdef printf
#undef printf
#endif
    printf("HELLO WORLD\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "HERE");
    fflush(stderr);

...
```

Any pointer with pertaining to this is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This was to do with the system library /usr/lib/libxml2.dylib taking precedence over the local library during execution

Thus my code wasn't getting picked up.

The changes took effect after setting environmental variables related to loading of dynamic libraries

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
#ifdef fprintf
#undef fprintf
#endif

#ifdef printf
#undef printf
#endif

printf("HELLO WORLD\n");
fprintf(stderr, "HERE");
```

Note: Those `undef` macros have no effect on the functions `printf()` and `fprintf()`, which are from the `libc6.so` library not from any `xml` library.

The reason your not seeing the result of the call to `printf()` and the call to `fprintf()` is because the posted code is not ever executed (and probably not even linked to your program).

To have these 'substitute' functions executed:

1. they must be compiled
2. they must be linked before the standard `xml` library

Therefore, please post your compile statement(s) and your link statement.  Then we can be of further assistance.